# Why indy/sovrin stores claims/verifiable-credentials/attestations in ledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

Videos and documentation always say claims are stored in the ledger but only the "credential definition" or "Schemas and claim definitions". Is this really needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As Verifiable Credentials typically contain private data, verifiable claims **are not stored** on ledger.
- Credential Schemas **are written on the ledger**. They don't contain any private data and only specify what certain type of document contains. For example, it might specify that a driving licence document should contain name, surname, date of birth of the holder, plus classes of vehicles the holder is eligible to drive. Schema is simply a template according to which an issuer may issue verifiable claims.
- Credential Definitions **are also written on the ledger**. It also doesn't contain any private data. Credential definition is linked to 1 Credential Schema (which must already exist on ledger). Credential Definition contains public key which an issuer uses to issue Verifiable Claim of certain type.

### Example for context

- Government decides that every university diploma in the country will have following fields: `Name`, `Surname`, `University name`, `Program`, `Degree`. **They write Credential Schema** `Diploma:1.0.0` on the ledger. Anyone can see how diploma looks like. Universities can use it to issue diplomas (as verifiable credentials) for students.
- `Faber Uni.` is university in the country. It wants to issue university degrees according to government specification of how diploma should look like. So `Faber Uni` **writes on ledger credential Definition** `Faber:Diploma:1.0.0`. This credential definition also contains public key `123` of `Faber Uni` for issuing credentials of this type (`Faber Uni` will safely keeps somewhere private part `456`). Each time `Faber Uni` issues a student diploma as verifiable credential, it will sign the data using the private part of the key, `456`.
- When `Faber Uni` issues diploma for its graduate `Bob`, there's **no trace of this event** on the ledger. `Faber Uni` simply signs a document conforming the `Diploma:1.0.0` schema which is on the ledger, using private key `456`, whose public counterpart `123` is on the ledger.
- Now `Bob` wants to get a job at `Abcd` and is asked to prove his education. He submits the credential issued by `Faber Uni`, which he safely stores on his device. `Abcd` could **read from the ledger `Faber Uni`'s diploma signing key**  and use it to verify signatures on the verifiable claim presented by `Bob`.

Comment: There's a nice document dedicated to this topic. "What Goes On The Ledger" by Evernym company https://www.evernym.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/What-Goes-On-The-Ledger.pdf